# Java code not compiling with a SQL statement

Tags: java

I am trying to delete a record from a database using the following code in Java

```
try {
    Statement st = db.con.createStatement();
    con.stmt = st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM item, WHERE Name=" + textField_name.getText());
```

however "stmt", (which is my PreparedStatement initialized in my connection class), is underlined and the code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `executeUpdate` returns an `int`, and presumably `con.stmt` isn't an `int` variable.

You shouldn't write your SQL that way in the first place though (it's invalid anyway due to the comma after `item`) - you should use a prepared statement:

```
PreparedStatement st = db.con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM item WHERE Name=?");
st.setString(1, textField_name.getText());
int rowsDeleted = st.executeUpdate();
```

That way you don't open yourself up to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Like I said I have initialized my PreparedStatement in my connection class... I don't really understand what the second line is doing do you mind just explaining please as I am new to java.

Comment: @FatmaTurk: That's not the way prepared statements work though. You prepare the statement with the SQL, then set the parameters. It's not clear how you've prepared the statement before the code you've shown us, but the code you've shown definitely won't work, whereas the code I've shown should.

Comment: I am still getting the following error [java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)]

Comment: @Jon Skeet, he is using a Statement and not a PreparedStatement class, so therefore, his st.executeUpdate(......) would work, BAD practice, but it works, it's basically executing a regular SQL statement. But the comma after item is an issue, but that would not cause a compiler error, more of a runtime error.

Comment: @Churk: No, it wouldn't work - because (as I said in the very first sentence) he's trying to assign the result to `con.stmt`. That's what's causing the compiler error.

Comment: @JonSkeet you assumed con.stmt is not an int, and it is a good assumption, and I probably would assume the same, and since he verified that is the case, then you are right. But con.stmt could very well be defined as an int, and that set could work. And since he did not show us the compiler error, we could only assume that you are right.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess what i am saying is, you example might have fixed more than 1 issue.

Comment: @Churk: Actually, the post now says (I'm not sure whether it did before 'however "stmt", (which is my PreparedStatement initialized in my connection class)' - which pretty much answers that. Basically I believe the OP did indeed have a number of problems. Hopefully using the code I've provided will have fixed them all...

Comment: @Jon Skeet -Yes the code you have provided did fix all the problems and your assumption about "stmt" not been an int was correct which I believe another reason for the code to work. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

`st.executeUpdate()` returns an `int`.

I think you wanted to execute `con.stmt.executeUpdate()`

Comment: now I understand why it was asking me to change "stmt" to "int"